# Select statement to return an updated table with duplicates on three columns filtered out

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What select statement would return an updated table from the following table where the rows which are duplicates on all three columns have been filtered out.

```
ID      Date                        Username    
2368    2012-01-31  00:00:00        asmith  
2368    2012-08-23  00:00:00        asmith  
3151    2012-01-05  00:00:00        asmith  
3151    2012-01-11  00:00:00        asmith  
3151    2012-01-11  00:00:00        asmith  
3171    2012-02-01  00:00:00        asmith  
3412    2012-03-27  00:00:00        asmith  
3420    2012-03-19  00:00:00        asmith  
3423    2012-07-12  00:00:00        asmith  
3431    2012-04-04  00:00:00        asmith  
3460    2012-03-10  00:00:00        asmith  
3519    2013-12-17  00:00:00        asmith  
3539    2012-05-21  00:00:00        asmith  
3541    2012-07-03  00:00:00        asmith  
3572    2012-03-22  00:00:00        asmith  
3572    2012-03-24  00:00:00        asmith  
3572    2012-03-25  00:00:00        asmith  
3572    2012-03-25  00:00:00        asmith
```

So after the duplicates for ID values 3151 and 3572 have been removed the resulting table will look like this.

```
ID      Date                        Username    
2368    2012-01-31  00:00:00        asmith  
2368    2012-08-23  00:00:00        asmith  
3151    2012-01-05  00:00:00        asmith
3171    2012-02-01  00:00:00        asmith  
3412    2012-03-27  00:00:00        asmith  
3420    2012-03-19  00:00:00        asmith  
3423    2012-07-12  00:00:00        asmith  
3431    2012-04-04  00:00:00        asmith  
3460    2012-03-10  00:00:00        asmith  
3519    2013-12-17  00:00:00        asmith  
3539    2012-05-21  00:00:00        asmith  
3541    2012-07-03  00:00:00        asmith  
3572    2012-03-22  00:00:00        asmith  
3572    2012-03-24  00:00:00        asmith
```

Comment: in your desired result you have 3151 only once, but in the sample data there are 3 occurences and only 2 have the same values. So why do you have it only once in stead of 2 times in the desired result ?

Comment: For 3151 there are 3 rows - 1 is unique and 2 are duplicates - the two duplicates need to be removed leaving just the 1 unique row

Comment: The alternative query in JaydipJ answer is what you are looking for I tested it and it returns exact what you asked for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE Row_NUMBER

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  select id, date, username,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id,Date ORDER BY ID) RN 
  from TABLE
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN=1
```

Alternative way to do this

```
select id, date, username
from TABLE
GROUP BY id, date, username
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: you still have 2 rows for 3151 and 3 rows for 3572

Comment: The alternative returns exact what the OP asked but the first statement still returns to many rows

Comment: @JaydipJ thank you - your second script does the business - cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below script .

```
;with cte_1 
 as 
 (SELECT COUNT(CareID)OVER(partition by CareID, TreatDate, Username order by CareID) CNT,* 
                FROM  tmpHANAPATH_Treatments WHERE Username = @Username) 
    SELECT * FROM cte_1 
    WHERE CNT=1
```

Comment: that doesn't work - one of the duplicates for 3151 and 3572 remains

Comment: I'm getting a Incorrect syntax near 'order' message?

Comment: i couldn't see any error in syntax..can you give your updated script?

Comment: ;with cte_1
as (select  COUNT(1)OVER(partition by CareID, TreatDate, Username order by CareID) CNT,*
from tmpHANAPATH_Treatments WHERE Username = @Username)
SELECT *
FROM cte_1
WHERE CNT=1